# Trigger an event when file is upload on managed_file field

Tags: 7, forms, javascript, ajax, files

I'm trying to trigger an javascript function when a user select an image for a managed_file field and click on the upload button, not the submit one.Except that in Drupal 7, managed_filr field do not accept ajax argument, I don't have any idea on how to solve my problem.
Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. I decide to use the '#upload_validators' parameter on my form and to declare my own function:

```
'#upload_validators' => array(
  'myOwnFunction' => array(parameters)
),
.
.
.

function myOwnFunction(parameters){
do stuff();
}
```